# How to order a MYSQL query by another query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a PHP/MYSQL search function which takes a users search query (as a string) and matches it to records from a table by predefined fields and quantities (eg: bedrooms = 2, max_price < 100)

This is working fine, but now I want to order the results by a condition. So for example:

- The users query is "*2 Bedroom Penthouse*"
- The function matches records that have a value of **2** for the row
  **bedrooms**

I now want to keep the results that match, but order the results by the results that match for a description row with a value of "**penthouse**" (anywhere in the description string (which is a long string of lots of words))

I can match the results that have the word "penthouse" in the description, but what is the best way to order the results with the matched results first?

So, basically, how do you order results by another query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. You write a more complex `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT ...
  ORDER BY ..., description NOT LIKE "%penthouse%"
```

(We invert the expression since false orders before true)

Comment: I forgot to mention, how do I handle multiple words within the query string (eg: penthouse with jacuzzi). So how do I rank by the description which has the most of the words from the search string? I have exploded the search query string into an array if that helps?

Comment: That is harder. You'll need to get the count of matches first, then reverse order the result.

Comment: It occurs to me that boolean expressions return `0` or `1`, so you could just sum up all the `LIKE` results.

Comment: Could you give me an example on this or a link to somewhere online with an example by any chance? (not being lazy, just not even sure what to search for :) )